# How to check wether Speech Recognition is Available or not?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

When I am initializing a Speech recognition app, I use this line of code:

```
Boolean b=SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(cContext);
```

Why does b always equals false on some devices (the emulator for example)?
I understand what the function does from its description on Android documentation, but the documentation does not say what to do to make voice recognition available.
Do I have to setup something else on my emulator? 
Do you know how to make Speech recognition always available?

Comment: You can try pocketsphinx http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

Comment: The problem IS real, so don't downvote before knowing. I solved it myself. The ultimate solution is to verify programmatically, that Google Search app is INSTALLED and ENABLED. This is usually present on most phones, except for some weird models and the emulator. If not, the best practice is to take the user to the Play Store for download/update, or to the App Info screen within settings to enable. I did it, and it worked, if you need the code just let me know.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem IS real, so don't downvote before knowing. I solved it myself. The ultimate solution is to verify programmatically, that Google Search app is INSTALLED and ENABLED. If not, the best practice is to use intents to take the user to the Play Store for download/update, or to the App Info screen within settings to enable it. I did it, and it worked, if you need the code just let me know.

Comment: Yeah. Could you provide with the sample code? It's too late :P

Comment: could you provide the code? did you navigate to playstore?

Comment: @Josh Any idea why SpeechRecognizer on Android 2.3.3 now reports “Couldn’t Connect”? Was there an announcement by Google to retire the speech recognition servers that supported Android 2.2? Interestingly enough, **same exact** app's code & build **does not** produce this error on Android 8.1.0.